# Android FileProvider fails to share a file using gmail and Google drive

Tags: android, audio, gmail, drive, android-fileprovider

Using Android FileProvider, when I try to share a file using gmail it fails, I get this gmail toast message: "Couldn't attach file".

It also puts a text string showing the file name and path in the 'To' area of the gmail.

When I try to share a file using Google drive it fails, I get the message:

Upload was unsuccessful
Unable to schedule 1 file for upload.

My question:

Did I miss something in my code? Please provide code with your answer.

XML code:

ANDROIDMANIFEST.XML

```
<application

<provider
android:name="android.support.v4.content.FileProvider"
android:authorities="com.mydomain.audiorecorder.fileprovider"
android:exported="false"
android:grantUriPermissions="true">
<meta-data
    android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
    android:resource="@xml/file_paths" />
</provider>

</application>
```

---

res/xml/file_paths.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<paths xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <files-path name="my_audio" path="AudioRecorder/"/>
</paths>
```

---

Java code:

```
case R.id.context_menu_share:

            /** ***********************************************
             *  Share Recording feature, code with FileProvider
             *  ***********************************************
             */

Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);

final String rowName2 = (itemNameArray.get(info.position));

File filePath = new File(this.getFilesDir(), "/AudioRecorder/");

File newFile = new File(filePath, rowName2);

Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "newFile = " + newFile, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

Uri uri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(this, "com.mydomain.audiorecorder.fileprovider", newFile);

Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "uri = " + uri, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);

i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, new String[]{"add@email-address.com"});

i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT,"Test");

i.setDataAndType(uri, "audio/wav");

i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uri);

this.startActivity(i);

try {
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(i, "Share..."));
} catch (android.content.ActivityNotFoundException ex) {
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "There are no email clients installed.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
 }
return true;
```